# How to tell cmake to use c89

Tags: c, cmake

So I recently decided to make the switch to using c89 only for my code from now on. I use cmake and i'm not sure how to tell cmake to use c89.

Per a information on a website it says "(accepted values are 98, 99 and 11)", which is really strange because 89 isn't there.

```
set (CMAKE_C_STANDARD 89)
```

This code gives me an error.

Whats really strange is that Ive searched everywhere on the web and couldn't find anyone asking about this.

Does anyone know how to use/(restrict) to using only c89 in cmake.

the cmake document says to use

```
Supported values are:

90

C89/C90
```

This code works

```
set (CMAKE_C_STANDARD 90)
```

However I want the compiler to use just C89 not C90.

Comment: `to use C89 not C90.` what are the differences?

Comment: The GCC developers consider C89 and C90 to be the same so I'm not sure why you wouldn't just pick 90: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 90)` to use C89.

C89 is the same as C90, also called ANSI C.

Note: prefer to use `set_target_properties(your_target C_STANDARD 90)` explicitly on your target, so it doesn't affect other targets.